# What tag should be used for tools that harden the platform like ChaosMonkey?

Tags: support, tags

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_Monkey), ChoasMonkey is used to test resilience of IT infrastructure. What about creating a [resilience](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resilience) or [resilience-testing](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resilience-testing) tag? Note: in the mean time this tag has been created and assigned to [this Q&A](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3976/210). If this tag should not have been created then it could be removed.

**Why this question?**

It turned out that a couple of tags were removed, while I was not notified. In order to prevent that Q&As that will be untagged again in the future I would like to discuss some tags first before creating them.

Comment: Tags are removed if not used for 6 months IIRC. There's not much to do about it. Both propositions are too vague for tags IMHO (I doubt someone will search within this tag specifically or follow it)

Answer (score 1):

The generalized term being used in the industry is "chaos engineering", see https://principlesofchaos.org/, writing from Netflix, writing from Gremlin.  Tag should be chaos-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I would like a chaos-monkey tag or "failure as a service". I work with that occasionally. Validating stuff and failing it.